# Pygame Backspace key on entered text not cleared. Overlapped instead/

Tags: python, pygame

Pic for better clarity of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV6Gh.jpg

As shown, I entered some text. Decided to backspace, instead the new text i entered was overlapping the previous one. Why is this happening?

New to pygame and stuck for this problem for too long already :(

Please help! What should i do

```
   if not cheat:
        WIN = pygame.image.load("Assets/winBox.png")
        self.SCREEN.blit(WIN, (175, 230))
        winRect = pygame.Rect(175, 230, 250, 164)
        pygame.display.update(winRect)
        done = False

        while not done:
            self.CLOCK.tick(self.FPS)
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.STATE = 0
                    done = True

                if 219 <= mouse[0] <= 269 and 366 <= mouse[1] <= 378 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    # RESTART
                    self.STATE = 6
                    done = True

                elif 311 <= mouse[0] <= 375 and 366 <= mouse[1] <= 378 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    # MAIN MENU
                    self.STATE = 2
                    done = True


    else:
        WIN = pygame.image.load("Assets/winBoxWithScore.png")
        self.SCREEN.blit(WIN, (175, 230))
        winRect = pygame.Rect(175, 230, 250, 164)


        pygame.display.update(winRect)
        done = False

        while not done:
            self.CLOCK.tick(self.FPS)
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.STATE = 0
                    done = True

                if 219 <= mouse[0] <= 269 and 366 <= mouse[1] <= 378 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    # RESTART
                    self.STATE = 6
                    done = True

                if 311 <= mouse[0] <= 375 and 366 <= mouse[1] <= 378 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    # MAIN MENU
                    self.STATE = 2
                    done = True

                elif 290 <= mouse[0] <= 345 and 275 <= mouse[1] <= 325 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:

                    WIN = pygame.image.load("Assets/winBoxBlank.png")
                    self.SCREEN.blit(WIN, (175, 230))
                    winRect = pygame.Rect(175, 230, 250, 164)

                    pygame.display.update(winRect)
                    name = ""
                    done = False
                    while not done:
                        self.CLOCK.tick(self.FPS)
                        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                        self.SCREEN.blit(
                            pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 22).render("Enter your name :", True, Color.black),
                            (210, 250))
                        # Textbox
                        pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, Color.gray, (210, 310, 180, 35), 2)

                        for event in pygame.event.get():
                            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                self.STATE = 0
                                done = True

                            # Keyboard events
                            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                                    name = name[:-1]  # remove last char


                                elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN or event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                                    done = True  # break out of the while loop to return name
                                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                                    self.menu()
                                    done = True

                                else:
                                    try:
                                        name += event.unicode  # Append name
                                    except:
                                        pass
                        # Limit name to 10 characters
                        name = name[:10]
                        # Display characters typed
                        if len(name) != 0:
                            self.SCREEN.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 22).render(name, True, Color.black),(230, 310))

                        pygame.display.update()

                    # Store score to the current textfile
                    p = Player(name, self.numdisks, str(len(self.moveList)))
                    with open("score.txt", "a") as sfile:
                        sfile.write("\n" + p.getName() + "\t" + str(p.getLevel()) + "\t" + str(p.getMove()))
                    # Navigate to the next page
                    self.STATE = 11
```

Comment: if the old text isn't clearing, then I imagine it isn't updating like it should. Are you updating the text box as you delete characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are redrawing the text label, the text box, and the name on each update:

```
self.SCREEN.blit(pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 22).render("Enter your name :", True, Color.black), (210, 250))
# Textbox
pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, Color.gray, (210, 310, 180, 35), 2)
```

But you are not clearing the text box inside. The issue is you are drawing a rectangle that isn't filled. The last argument for drawing a rectangle is the width. you have it set to 2. So it is drawing a rectangle, but not filled.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect

if you add a filled rectangle as well (for inside the text box) it will clear the name each time and only fill it with the current name.

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.SCREEN, color_of_your_choice, (212, 312, 176, 31))
```

you have to adjust the x, y, width and height to account for the slightly smaller rectangle to fit inside the outer box